# How to vertically middle-align floating elements of unknown heights?

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I have a (horizontally) centered outer div containing two elements of unknown width:

```
<div style='width:800px; margin:0 auto'>
  <div style='float:left'>...</div>
  <div style='float:right'>...</div>
</div>
```

Both floats are top-aligned by default, and are of varying/unknown and different heights. Is there any way to make them vertically centered?

I eventually made the outer div

```
display: table
```

and the inner divs

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left/right;
```

but I'm just curious if there's a way to do this with the floats.

Comment: vertical align in html/css is beyond ugly, and the primary source of my aching desire to slap the entire W3C around with the rotting corpse of IE6, then feed them that corpse.

Comment: @MarcB You aren't alone, but this is what we have to work with....

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can't do this directly, because [floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) are aligned to the top:

> If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned
>   with the top of the current line box.

The exact [rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules) say (emphasis mine):

> 4. A floating box's [outer top](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#outer-edge) may not be higher than the top of its [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block).
> 5. The [outer top](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#outer-edge) of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any [block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) or [floated](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) box generated by an
>      element earlier in the source document.
> 6. The [outer top](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#outer-edge) of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top of any [line-box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box) containing a box generated by an
>      element earlier in the source document.
>
> 8. **A floating box must be placed as high as possible.**

That said, you can take advantage of rule #4:

- Place each float inside [inline-level](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes) elements that establish a new [block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) /BFC), e.g. `display: inline-block`.
- These wrappers will contain the floats because they establish a BFC, and will be one next to the other because they are inline-level.
- Use [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) to align these wrapper vertically.

Be aware that some space might appear between the inline-block wrappers. See [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630) to fix it.

```css
.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}

/* Float wrappers */
#main > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <div class="float-left">
      <p>AAA</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="float-right">
      <p>BBB</p>
      <p>BBB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution work because you put `width:49%;` even without float div it will work.

Comment: I was looking for solution like this for a long time.
Thanks!

Comment: I realize this definitely has applications, but it seems kinda cheating to me. the only thing `float: right` does here is to right justify the BBB content. it's the `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` that actually does the centering. it's not really vertically centering floated content at all.

Comment: The float shouldn't even be used here. It serves no purpose other than to justify content right like @Simon_Weaver mentioned. Instead  it would be better to use `text-align: right` that way the div height will be a part of the flow of the page w/out using a clearfix.

Comment: @newms87 Probably true. But then there won't be any float, so it wouldn't answer the question. Now I think I answer it, even if I cheat a little.

Comment: there's nothing with cheating sometimes (or more than sometimes with CSS) ;-) but it's just important the people don't blindly copy code snippets like this without really understanding them - or they'll end up with unexpected and confusing side effects later on

Comment: It does not work well for another reason -- the content is vertically centered to itself. If you change the height of the container manually you will see both parts are really on the top of the container.

Comment: @greenoldman If the parent has an explicit height, you can insert an inline-level pseudo-element with `height: 100%` and `vertical-align: middle` ([centering in the unknown](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) technique).

Answer (score 10):

Another approach would be to use `flex` -- it could be a replacement for a `float` if you have two parts. One (floating) would be of auto size, and the second would grow to occupy entire container. On the cross axis you pick `center` and voila, you have the **effect** of the float and centered elements.

Here is beautiful cheatsheet about flex: http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/

Comment: Of course you run up against the horror that is IE when you try to [use flex](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). :-|

Comment: That cheatsheet is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Nope this is when table cells suddenly seem like a great idea. If it is a fixed height you can use line-height.

Comment: And if someone is allergic to using tables for layout, css tables can be also used (even though under the hood those are still tables).

Comment: Table is not so good if you want responsive layout that will naturally flow to show underneath the left element on narrow viewports.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that is completely untrue if you are using css tables. Just change the table display to a block display when needed, within the right css query.

Comment: @Babydead the whole table... sure. For individual td elements in the same row, it's weird.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn of course. Though, the idea of a table is that all of your data is presented in the same way. I can't think of a situation where you would need elements to behave differently from others responsively, when they are aligned the same in non-responsive form. I've built over 250 responsive websites and never came across anything where this was an issue. I'd love to see an example if you have one, though. Quite curious!