# center dynamic content vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering

I've search through the internet for my issue and I always find the same solution, but it doesn't work out for me.. something in my code is different then in the examples of 'vertically center' dynamic content in a div.

I've this webpage
http://staging.karlienfabre.be/pocoloco/reizen/canyoning.html

And the issue is at the first yellow section. I would like that the text on the left is centered vertically; but the text can have different lengths; the white box on the right should also be centered vertically.

At this moment the html is looking like this

```
 <div class="container yellow-content">
    <div class="row center-vertical">
        <div class="col-md-7 vertical-center-element">
            <h2>Actie en avontuur</h2>
            <p>
                540 smith grind grind hang up launch ramp. Sponsored gnarly no comply regular footed hang-up. Quarter pipe tic-tac aerial hang ten airwalk. Deck baseplate crail grab bluntslide regular footed. Varial carve darkslide ollie hole Vans Calfornia Daze rocket air. Pivot kick-nose ollie sketchy death box Steve Rocco.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 bgwhite vertical-center-element">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="text-center testimonial">
                        <a href=""> <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="../img/reisaanbod/testimonials/testi_canyoning.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="row-md-9">
                        <p>Tic-tac nollie bearings Ron Allen disaster. Downhill blunt no comply Kevin Jarvis slob air. Deck Brooklyn Banks indy grab slap maxwell pop shove-it.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css I think is important

```
.row.center-vertical{
    display: table;
}
.vertical-center-element{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I can't find what I'm doing wrong or what makes that the centering is not working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.vertical-center-element{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

to

```
.vertical-center-element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

You have `float: left` on the element which is preventing it from vertically aligning. The above code (specifically `float:none`) overrides it.

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

In your case, why not change:

```
<div class="col-md-7 vertical-center-element">
        <h2>Actie en avontuur</h2>
```

to (NOTE col-md-8, not col-md-7)

```
<div class="col-md-8 vertical-center-element vertical-centered-text">
        <h2>Actie en avontuur</h2>
```

and apply the following to your CSS:

```
.vertical-center-element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

.vertical-centered-text {
    padding-right: 60px;
}
```

That way all your elements line up properly and your text is in the correct position. *And* you have made less changes to the css so you won't get unexpected changes to the bootstrap grid when scaled down etc.

Comment: Ok. As you said the content is now vertically aligned, but the div need to be floated: left.. any idea how the achieve both?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557897/how-to-vertically-middle-align-floating-elements-of-unknown-heights .  If not you could adjust the top margin using jquery or something?