# Vertically centering an inline-block element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a flash message popup, similar in style to what StackOverflow itself uses -

[image]

They accomplish it by floating the message to the left and floating the close button to the right. They also "center" the close button vertically by giving it a fixed `margin-top` as shown in the diagram.

My flash message is slightly different in that the message is centered.

[image]

At a high level I approached it as follows -

- Message and close button are 2 `<div>`s that are displayed as `inline-block`
- The message takes up the middle 80% of the width, which leaves 10% on each side. There's a `margin-left` of 10% for this reason.
- The close button naturally takes up the rightmost 10%
- I didn't use `float: right` because I know [there's some difficulty in vertically centering floated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557897/how-to-vertically-middle-align-floating-elements-of-unknown-heights).

I'm having the hardest time vertically centering the close button, as shown above. It just hugs the bottom.

My HTML and CSS are below - is there any straightforward way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

#### HTML:

```
<div id="flash" class="center active error">
  <div class="flash-message">
    Please enter an email. Please enter an email. Please enter an email. Please enter an email. Please enter an email. Please enter an email.
  </div>
  <div class="flash-close">x</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
// Flash messages
#flash {
  // Display it as an offset from the parent <body> tag
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 4em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  // Center it on the page
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;

  z-index: 101;
  line-height: 2.5;
  overflow: hidden;

  // Cool shadows
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px $black;
  border-radius: 3px;

  // Set color based on message type
  &.error { background: $mustard; }
  &.notice { background: $light-green; }

  .flash-message {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    padding-left: (100% - 80%)/2;

    // Give it 3px on the top and bottom for some space
    margin: 3px 0;
  }

  .flash-close {
    display: inline-block;
    // This doesn't seem to do anything.... -_-
    // I've also tried auto-setting margins, and making it `position: relative`
    // so I can set top/bottom as 50%
    vertical-align: middle;

    // Give it 3px on the top and bottom for some space
    // Also 11px from the right edge
    margin: 3px 11px 3px 0;

    // Styling the "X" and the box around it
    padding: 2px 6px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: $white;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to specify `height: 100%` for both of your nested divs

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/code4pi/yyrko1zw/

In newer browsers, you can use the display flex property.

Just add the following to your existing classes:

```
#flash {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flash-close {
    align-self: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try centering using flexbox.

```
#flash {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Additional information: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Agreed, it seems much simpler here. code4pi had a similar solution as well which seems to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just played around with your code, you need to add the following to your css:

Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/max234435/tjhb3md8/ - working version of what I think you are looking for

`float: right;
display: table-cell;`