# Vertical align text middle to image when text is less

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text-image component, and i need to vertical-align text middle to the floated image , if the text is less (condition one) (for larger screens). if the text is more then let it wrap around the floated image (condition two) (again for larger screens). How can i do this in CSS or do we need Javascript for this? Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hmfn25w/1/). Both my conditions one and two should work.

```css
 .clearfix { clear: both; }
.text-img { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; }
.text-img .info-box .info--body p { max-width: none; }
.text-img .info-box { text-align: justify; }
.text-img .stock-img { width: 100%; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .text-img.text-right .stock-img { width: 50%; float: left; }
  .text-img.text-right  .stock-img { padding-right: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; }

  .text-img.text-left .stock-img { width: 50%; float: right; }
  .text-img.text-left  .stock-img { padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix text-img text-left">
 <img src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/gvDQZLtlEM7U99rmTEdMoUtLRJU=/0x96:2039x1243/1600x900/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/50319283/ipad1_2040.0.0.jpg" alt="iPad" class="img-responsive stock-img" />
 <div class="info-box">
  <header class="info--header">
   <h3 class="h3">The science of today is the technology of tomorrow.</h3>
  </header>
  <div class="info--body">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc semper urna nec lectus malesuada tincidunt. Aenean faucibus, nulla sed luctus tempus, purus libero vestibulum velit, et blandit odio nunc ac quam. Donec tellus tellus, venenatis ac diam nec, sodales viverra orci.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want the final output to be like this, which satisfys both my condition:

[image]

Well the answers given are right, this cannot be solved just by CSS alone, so i had to come up with jQuery solution. For those looking for solution for such scenarios, here is jQuery code that solved my problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".text-img").each( function() {
        var cH = parseInt( $( this ).height() );
        var tH = parseInt( $( this ).find('.info-box').height() );

        if( tH < cH ) {
            var pt = ( cH - tH ) / 2;

            $( this ).find('.info-box').css({
                "padding-top" : pt + "px"
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Vishwa, kindly check if my solution works, and let me know your feedback... `:D`

Comment: You cannot vertically align a floated element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557897/how-to-vertically-middle-align-floating-elements-of-unknown-heights

Comment: From the [Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats): A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line. The most interesting characteristic of a float (or "floated" or "floating" box) is that content may flow along its side (or be prohibited from doing so by the 'clear' property). Content flows down the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a right-floated box. The following is an introduction to float positioning and content flow; the exact rules governing float behavior are given in the description of the 'float' property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a flex box layout when you are in the smaller screens.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .text-left {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .text-left img {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

[image: preview]

**Output: http://jsbin.com/lulecudaji/edit?html,css,output**

Comment: but if the text is more , then your code does not wrap around the image

Comment: @VishwaKumar Do you really need to float the image? If you float it, you cannot vertically align.

Comment: Yes that is also a condition :), i want the image to be floated

Comment: @VishwaKumar Not possible boss. You cannot vertically align a floated element.

Comment: @VishwaKumar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557897/how-to-vertically-middle-align-floating-elements-of-unknown-heights

Comment: @VishwaKumar From the [Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats): A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line. The most interesting characteristic of a float (or "floated" or "floating" box) is that content may flow along its side (or be prohibited from doing so by the clear property). Content flows down the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a right-floated box. The following is an introduction to float positioning and content flow; the exact rules governing float behavior are given in the description of the 'float' property.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you better/older than flex-box tick for centring elements.

For horizontal centring use simply `text-align: center;` on container div

For vertical centring uses propoerty of display inline-block elements which aligned in to the middle to center all display inline-block in the line.

[image]

Making it bigger i'll move other elements to the center
[image]

Making it 100% height causes the othere elements centers to the middle.
[image]

You simply need to create ghost (not visible) - red element to center content - blue and green elements.

For ghost element use for it before or after of conteiner div:

```
.continer:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And display inline-block your content:

```
.content{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Of course delete `position:absolute` etc.

Last tweak will be to get rid of that small spaces between elements (especially between red and others) use one of the tricks from here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
Probably you will need to set font size to zero.

More about ghost elements:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Sorry but this is not what i need , please read my question once again, thank you for your reply.

Comment: It is the closest thing you can get with css only. 

You can not align float element becuse their are... floats. Floating element is taking it from the "scope" and moving it to left or right edge and "the top of the current line box" https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats.