# Vertically middle align floated contents

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I'm following this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558070/2968762) to vertically align a div's contents that has `float: left` styling:

```css
.main {
  height: 85px;
}

.child_1,
.child_2 {
  float: left;
  width: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="child_1">
      Some long text is put here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="child_2">
      22
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, it doesn't vertically align as per the height of the wrapper div **main**. What is wrong in the code?

Comment: You can't use `float` and `vertical-align`...it just doesn't work...nor does it do what you think it does.

Comment: I have edited your CSS to increase `.child_1`'s font-size is that ok?

Comment: @Ivan Sorry thats a typo. I meant **longer text**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

to `.main` class, it should work.

```css
.main {
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #f00;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 2rem;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.child_1,
.child_2 {
  float: left;
  width: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="child_1">
      Some long text is put here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="child_2">
      22
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the linked question, you can see that the *line box* aligns itself, but not *exactly* with the `main` - try setting a `height` for the `main` and you'll see.

You've `height` set for the `main` here and that makes all the difference. For this you can use a *psuedo* element to *center*:

```
.main:after{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.main {
  height: 85px;  
  border: 1px solid;
}

.child_1,
.child_2 {
  float: left;
}

.main:after{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="child_1">
      Some long text is put here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="child_2">
      22
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```