# Vertical align floated elements of unknown height

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I want to create a header with two columns, one for the "brand name" and one for buttons, such as login, sign up etc.

However I can't wrap my head around how to vertical center them inside the header, because the buttons are much taller than the brand name.

I also already stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557897), however the solution suggested there did not resolve my issue.

**What I have got so far:**

```css
header {
  border: 1px dotted magenta;
}
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#left {
  background-color: #cfc;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#right {
  background-color: #ccf;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="left">
    My brand name
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</header>
```

As you can see in the snippet above, the text `My brand name` is vertically aligned to the top. However, the desired result would be the text being vertically centered inside the header. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox**, you just need to use `align-items: center` on `header` for vertical align.

```css
header {
  border: 1px dotted magenta;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#left {
  background-color: #cfc;
}
#right {
  background-color: #ccf;
}
button {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="left">
    My brand name
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The are two more solution to achieve that:

**Variant 1** with table, works in IE 6+

```css
header {
  border: 1px dotted magenta;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#left {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#right {
  background-color: #ccf;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="left">
    My brand name
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</header>
```

or look here https://codepen.io/artysimple/pen/XeEjbj?editors=1100

**Variant 2** with position and transformer works in IE 9+

```css
header {
  border: 1px dotted magenta;
  position: relative;
}
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #cfc;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#right {
  background-color: #ccf;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="left">
    My brand name
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</header>
```

or look here https://codepen.io/artysimple/pen/dVmpXd